# How can I maintain the hover state on my main tab but not let it affect my sub tabs?

Tags: html, css

I have a specific hover effect on my "menu" tab that I would like to keep, but it also applies that hover effect on the sub tabs within it. How can I prevent this from happening?? I've attached the part of my code that causes the effect.

```
`nav ul li:hover > a
{
 color:#f9b97a;
 border-bottom:2px solid #f9b97a;
 transition:all 0.3s ease-in;
 padding:14px;
}`
```

Comment: Your selectors are not specific enough to target only the parent anchor tags. It will target all `<a>` tags where the parent element matches `li:hover`, so it cascades to your sub menus as well. adding specific class names to the elements that you want to apply the rule will give you specific control over the parent and not the child.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing you HTML, my guess would be:

```
nav > ul > li:hover > a
{
   color:#f9b97a;
   border-bottom:2px solid #f9b97a;
   transition:all 0.3s ease-in;
   padding:14px;
}
```

This means you are only selecting ul that is a direct child of nav.